# Spyder hanged after executing python code

Tags: python, spyder

I have a few variables with length greater than `200k items` with each item being a dictionary. I extracted this from even more complex variables.

Every time i would perform some operation on them and execute the code, `Spyder` would hang but after a few mins, it would show/print the result.

Now, again I executed another operation and `Spyder` has hanged again. However, it is still not responding. It's been `15+` mins.

Previously memory usage was 23%, now it is 67%. My laptop has `16GB RAM`.

Will I lose my variables if `Spyder` is closed and opened again? Will I lose my file? The changes in the file haven't been saved.

Comment: If you kill a running Python program then you will lose whatever state the program is in. Perhaps you could rewrite the program so that it periodically pickles the relevant part of the state.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We improved memory usage management significantly in our consoles in our 3.3.0 version. Our last version is 3.3.3, so if you're using an older version, please update and try again.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm currently using 3.3.2. I'll upgrade. Thanks!